# Merging 2 query and remove duplicate firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've written 2 query :

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> users = usersRef
    .where("displayNameSearch", arrayContains: query.toLowerCase())
    .snapshots();

Stream<QuerySnapshot> users2 = usersRef
    .where("usernameSearch", arrayContains: query.toLowerCase())
    .snapshots();

setState(() {
  searchResultsDisplayName = users;
  searchResultsUsername = users2;
});
```

But both could return the same docs, so i would like to know if there is a way to merge both result in a way that there is no duplicating ?

**Update**

After the answer of Frank i trie to do it like that :

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: searchResultsDisplayName,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: searchResultsUsername,
            builder: (context, snapshot2) {
              if (!snapshot2.hasData) {
                return circularProgress();
              }
              List<UserResult> searchResults = [];
              snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
                User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
                UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
                searchResults.add(searchResult);
              });
              snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
                snapshot2.data.documents.forEach((doc2) {
                  if (doc2['id'] != doc['id']) {
                    User user = User.fromDocument(doc2);
                    UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
                    searchResults.add(searchResult);
                  }
                });
              });
```

is it the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy, scalable way to exclude results from one query from another query. But you should be able to merge the results client-side by comparing the [`documentId` field](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/documentID.html) of every document with each other.

If you're having a hard time making that work, post what you've tried so that we can spot where you made a mistake.

---

**Update**: In your code you now do this:

```
snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
  snapshot2.data.documents.forEach((doc2) {
    if (doc2['id'] != doc['id']) {
      User user = User.fromDocument(doc2);
      UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
      searchResults.add(searchResult);
    }
  });
});
```

As soon as either snapshot has more than one result, this code won't work. I highly recommend stepping through this code in a debugger, so that you can see why it does't work.

You're more likely looking for something like this (it may contain syntax errors, as I didn't actually run it):

```
var merged = new List<DocumentSnapshot>();
snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
  merged.add(doc);
});
snapshot2.data.documents.forEach((doc2) {
  if (!merged.indexWhere((doc) => (doc2['id'] != doc['id']) >= 0) {
    merged.add(doc2);
  }
});
```